# Makefile: implicit rule with non-explicit output file name breaks rule matching

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm in a situation where I want multiple file types all preprocessed (if their name indicates).

For example:

```
main.c              # gets compiled normally by %.c rule
somethingelse.c.m4  # gets preprocessed, then dealt with by %.c rule
somethingother.h.m4 # gets preprocessed (then included by .c files)
```

what I tried:

```
%: %.m4
  m4 "$<" > "$@"
```

But I'm greeted with the error message:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'somethingelse.o', needed by 'a.out'.  Stop.
```

As you can see, this fails in the rule *after* the `m4` one.

Pretty sure it can't figure out that there'd ever be a `.c` file generated from this implicit rule, thus is unable to match the `%.o: %.c` one.

this works of course:

```
%.c: %.c.m4
  m4 "$<" > "$@"
%.h: %.h.m4
  m4 "$<" > "$@"
```

but it gets rather repetitive rather quick when adding cases.

is there any way to get this to work with a single rule matching those files?

*Before anyone tells me about the C preprocessor*: the `.c`/`.h` files here are just a "well known"/"minimal" example, in reality I'm dealing with various custom file formats, but the exact same logic and "implicit rule chaining" situation applies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Pretty sure it can't figure out that there'd ever be a .c file generated from this implicit rule, thus is unable to match the %.o: %.c one.

No, I think the answer is simpler.  Per [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Chained-Rules.html#Chained-Rules),

> for performance reasons `make` will not consider non-terminal
> match-anything rules (i.e., ‘%:’) when searching for a rule to build a
> prerequisite of an implicit rule

That is exactly your case.  The `somethingelse.c` file is not explicitly named as a target or preqrequisite of any rule; it is being considered only as a prerequisite of an implicit rule.  Your match-anything rule is not terminal, so it is not even considered for building that file.

The manual has more to say about [terminal *vs*. non-terminal match-anything rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Match_002dAnything-Rules.html#Match_002dAnything-Rules), but the key points relevant here are:

- a terminal match-anything rule is distinguished from a non-terminal one by use of a double colon instead of a single one to separate target from prerequisites, and
- a terminal rule applies only if all its prerequisites exist.

The requirement that all prerequisites exist is not a problem for the case presented in the question, and I find that switching to a terminal match-anything rule resolves the problem.  For example, this complete Makefile ...

```
OBJECTS = main.o somethingelse.o

foo: $(OBJECTS)
        $(CC) -o $@ $^

%:: %.m4
        m4 $< > $@
```

... works for me for building `foo` from suitable `main.c` and `somethingelse.c.m4`.

Comment: thanks a lot, I wasn't even aware of the distinction between terminal vs. non-terminal. as you said, given that the `%.m4` files are always handcrafted in this project, they always exist, so it works perfectly.